# Trying to figure out why some of the output isn't working

Tags: python

complete beginner here. I am trying to get each letter in a sentence to alternate between uppercase and lowercase. I was wondering why in the output of my code does the whole 'fox' and 'dog' stay all in lower case? I figured 1 or 2 but im lost at why all 3 in both words.

```
text = input('Enter a sentence: ')

def sponge(t):
    new = ''
    for i in t:
        if t.index(i) % 2 == 0:
            new += (i).lower()
        elif t.index(i) % 2 == 1:
            new += (i).upper()
    return new

print(sponge(text))
```

when I enter 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog' it does that. Also when I type something with 2 E's or 2 O's both will be capitalized even if they're next to each other.

Also I know there are easier ways to do this but I am not that far in learning yet so I am trying to do it with what I currently know as opposed to modules and all that. Thank you for your time.

Comment: i ran your code and it's fine `fox` -> `fOx` and `dog` -> `dOg`, `stackoverflow` -> `sTaCkOvErFlOw`.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention I was using the sentence 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog' and that's where fox and dog stayed lower case. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `t.index(i)`. That returns the position of the *first* occurrence of `i` in the string. If you have duplicate letters, you'll use the position of the first one when deciding what to do with all the repetitions.

Use `enumerate()` to get both the letter and its index at the same time.

```
def sponge(t):
    new = ''
    for index, letter in enumerate(t):
        if index % 2 == 0:
            new += letter.lower()
        else:
            new += letter.upper()
    return new
```

Without `enumerate` you can use `range(len(t))` and then access `t[index]`.

```
def sponge(t):
    new = ''
    for index in range(len(t)):
        if index % 2 == 0:
            new += t[index].lower()
        else:
            new += t[index].upper()
    return new
```

Or you can use a separate variable to keep track of whether it's an even or odd index.

```
def sponge(t):
    new = ''
    even = True
    for letter in t:
        if even:
            new += letter.lower()
        else:
            new += letter.upper()
        even = not even
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it work without enumerate? I haven't learned that yet and was trying to go with what I know so far. Like as of now I don't even know what enumerate does.

Comment: I've added additional methods